# Can I replace this switch with a 3-way switch?

Tags: electrical, wiring, lighting, switch

I want to replace the on/off switch for our attic fan, and this is the only switch in the house that I’m aware of that operates it. The wires are red, white, and black. Will a traditional 3-way switch work for this?

[image: attic fan switch]

[image: switch]

Comment: Does the fan have hi/lo speed? Is there a middle position on the switch?

Comment: @Harper I just checked, it in fact does. I just bought this house and never had an attic fan before, so I thought it only was on or off. Thanks for posing this question. I guess this sort of answers my question then.

Comment: Yeah, 3-way *plus* hi-lo would be a bridge too far. Well, maybe a purpose built fan speed control.

Comment: What are you after? Just changing the switch so it looks better? You can use a double three-way swich instead. One of the switch will toggle on/off, the other will toggle hi-lo speed. You can ask a follow-up question on how to wire it.

Comment: Yes, just trying to update the look. To keep it consolidated to a single switch, and not have to install a larger box to house two switches, I’ll probably look for a 2 speed switch that works in a similar fashion as the current switch.

Comment: "3-position switch" search on my hardware store website yields results that would work. Try it on yours.

Comment: Here is a center off switch that should work for you: https://www.amazon.com/dp/B003AUPP66/ref=cm_sw_r_cp_api_i_uk73AbVFADTK9

Comment: A better search term if you want to look around is “center off switch”, just watch out for “momentary” you do NOT want momentary, with momentary you have to manually hold it engaged, and it springs back to center off.